# Using 'prod' for a lot of numbers

Tags: r

I want to simplify my code. df is a dataframe consisting of 7 variables and I want the product of them.

```
df <- data.frame(0.5, 5, 9.8, 10.3, 5.7, 0.9, 19.0)
> prod(df[1], df[2], df[3], df[4], df[5], df[6], df[7])
[1] 24596.55
```

It is a lot of work if you've got more dataframes so I want a simple code to do this.

I thought something like this:

```
for(i in 1:7){
  product = prod(df[i])
}
> product
[1] 19
```

But that's not what I want. Can somebody help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just use 'prod' like this :

```
prod(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
> prod(t(df))
[1] 24596.55

> do.call(prod, df)
[1] 24596.55

> Reduce("*", df)
[1] 24596.55
```

where the `Reduce` approach is inefficient, thus not recommended.